# Developing SQL queries safely in Java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement, sql-injection

How do I develop multiple SQL conditions, and subsequently incorporate these conditions into a query along with the order by clause safely ?

I'm trying to write SQL statements with potentially multiple conditions and an order by clause e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE id = '4' AND (Multiple conditions)
ORDER BY (Column name and direction).
```

I have been using prepared statements up until now but it doesn't support having dynamic ORDER BY clause nor having multiple dynamic conditions. As such, my current approach involves using string concatenation to develop the conditions independently, and then using string formatting to add them to the query along with the order by clause. I believe this approach is vulnerable to SQL injection, and I have been unable to find a safe, alternate approach. I have considered dynamic querying, but I do not have access in this part of the pipeline. I also considered sanitization, but this would still leave vulnerability for JSON or HTML attack. I have also considered having independent query statements written out for each scenario, but this doesn't scale at all.

Any help is appreciated, I have been searching for a solution for sometime now.

EDIT: Here is a snippet.

static final String SELECT_DEALS =

```
"SELECT *
FROM #DEALS
WHERE DEAL_ID = ? AND NAME LIKE ? AND ?
ORDER BY ?";
```

The first two parameters work fine, the second two result in errors like

Comment: Have you considered `CriteriaBuilder` ?

Comment: _prepared statements ... doesn't support ... dynamic ORDER BY_ [edit] your question and post the code you tried and indicate why you decided that `PreparedStatement` doesn't support it.